# How to change font size variable on hover CSS

Tags: html, css, variables, sass

I'm new to CSS variable manipulation and haven't found an answer to a problem I'm facing. I have two separate font sizes depending on screen width. I'd like to dynamically increase these variables on hover. How can I do this? Is there a better way in general?

```css
$my-font-size: 1rem;
h1 {
  font-size: calc($my-font-size * 1.25);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 595px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: $my-font-size;
  }
}

h1:hover {
  $my-font-size: calc($my-font-size * 1.15);
}
```

Comment: why not use the calc function to multiple the variable of font-size?

Comment: feels like just use `h1:hover{
font-size: 1.15rem;
}`

Comment: Well, I'm trying to change the value of $my-font-size on hover. On hover, I want the value of $my-font-size to change to 1.15x its initial value of 1rem.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss but the intended behavior will be `1.4375rem` on screens larger than 595px and 1.15rem on screens at 595px or lower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define the variable for the font-size before and inside the media query. Then use `calc` to multiply the font-size on hover with the variable:

```css
:root {
  --font-size: 1.25rem;
}

@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 595px) {
    :root {
      --font-size: 1rem;
    }
}

h1 {
  font-size: var(--font-size);
}

h1:hover {
  font-size: calc(var(--font-size) * 1.15);
}
```

```html
<h1>Just a Test</h1>
```